# FuseMonsterAction implementation and unit tests

Tags: java, game, unit-testing, community-challenge

I'd like to get a general review on the following code, and I'll highlight an extra point below:

```
public interface PlayerAction {
    boolean isActionAllowed(final Player player);

    void performAction(final Player player) throws PlayerActionNotAllowedException;
}
```

---

```
public class PlayerActionNotAllowedException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4656594949564649L;

    public PlayerActionNotAllowedException() {
        super();
    }

    public PlayerActionNotAllowedException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public PlayerActionNotAllowedException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public PlayerActionNotAllowedException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PlayerActionNotAllowedExceptionTest {
    static {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        new PlayerActionNotAllowedException();
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructorMessage() {
        PlayerActionNotAllowedException exception = new PlayerActionNotAllowedException("Test");
        assertEquals("Test", exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructorMessageCause() {
        Throwable cause = new Throwable();
        PlayerActionNotAllowedException exception = new PlayerActionNotAllowedException("Test", cause);
        assertEquals("Test", exception.getMessage());
        assertEquals(cause, exception.getCause());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructorCause() {
        Throwable cause = new Throwable();
        PlayerActionNotAllowedException exception = new PlayerActionNotAllowedException(cause);
        assertEquals(cause, exception.getCause());
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class AbstractPlayerAction implements PlayerAction {
    @Override
    abstract public boolean isActionAllowed(final Player player);

    @Override
    public void performAction(final Player player) throws PlayerActionNotAllowedException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(player, "player");
        if (!isActionAllowed(player)) {
            throw new PlayerActionNotAllowedException();
        }
        internalPerformAction(player);
    }

    abstract protected void internalPerformAction(final Player player);
}
```

---

```
public class AbstractPlayerActionTest {
    static {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    private AtomicInteger counter;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPerformAction() {
        PlayerAction playerAction = new AbstractPlayerActionImpl();
        Player player = new Player("Test", 100, new TurnActionImpl(), new Hand(5), new Field(5), new Deck(Arrays.asList(new MonsterCard("Test", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING))), new Graveyard());
        playerAction.performAction(player);
        assertEquals(1, counter.get());
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testPerformActionNullPlayer() {
        PlayerAction playerAction = new AbstractPlayerActionImpl();
        playerAction.performAction(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionNotAllowed() {
        PlayerAction playerAction = new AbstractPlayerActionImpl() {
            @Override
            public boolean isActionAllowed(final Player player) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        Player player = new Player("Test", 100, new TurnActionImpl(), new Hand(5), new Field(5), new Deck(Arrays.asList(new MonsterCard("Test", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING))), new Graveyard());
        playerAction.performAction(player);
    }

    private class AbstractPlayerActionImpl extends AbstractPlayerAction {
        @Override
        public boolean isActionAllowed(final Player player) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void internalPerformAction(final Player player) {
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    private static class TurnActionImpl implements TurnAction {
        @Override
        public void performTurn(Player player) { }
    }
}
```

And now the class where the question is about:

```
public class FuseMonsterAction extends AbstractPlayerAction implements PlayerAction {
    private final int fusionCardIndex;
    private final int baseMonsterCardIndex;
    private final int fuserMonsterCardIndex;

    public FuseMonsterAction(final int fusionCardIndex, final int baseMonsterCardIndex, final int fuserMonsterCardIndex) {
        Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(baseMonsterCardIndex, "baseMonsterCardIndex");
        Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(fuserMonsterCardIndex, "fuserMonsterCardIndex");
        if (baseMonsterCardIndex == fuserMonsterCardIndex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("baseMonsterCardIndex == fuserMonsterCardIndex");
        }
        this.fusionCardIndex = Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(fusionCardIndex, "fusionCardIndex");
        this.baseMonsterCardIndex = baseMonsterCardIndex;
        this.fuserMonsterCardIndex = fuserMonsterCardIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActionAllowed(final Player player) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(player, "player");
        Hand hand = player.getHand();
        Field field = player.getField();
        if (fusionCardIndex >= hand.getCapacity()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (baseMonsterCardIndex >= field.getMonsterCapacity()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (fuserMonsterCardIndex >= field.getMonsterCapacity()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(hand.get(fusionCardIndex) instanceof FusionCard)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!field.hasMonster(baseMonsterCardIndex)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!field.hasMonster(fuserMonsterCardIndex)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void internalPerformAction(final Player player) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(player);
        Hand hand = player.getHand();
        Field field = player.getField();
        Graveyard graveyard = player.getGraveyard();
        FusionCard fusionCard = (FusionCard)hand.play(fusionCardIndex);
        MonsterCard baseMonsterCard = field.destroyMonster(baseMonsterCardIndex);
        MonsterCard fuserMonsterCard = field.destroyMonster(fuserMonsterCardIndex);
        MonsterCard fusedCard = baseMonsterCard.fuseWith(fuserMonsterCard, fusionCard);
        graveyard.add(baseMonsterCard);
        graveyard.add(fuserMonsterCard);
        graveyard.add(fusionCard);
        field.setMonster(baseMonsterCardIndex, fusedCard);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FuseMonsterActionTest {
    static {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    private Player player;

    private final PlayerConfiguration playerConfiguration = new PlayerConfigurationBuilder()
            .hitpoints(100)
            .turnAction(p -> { })
            .handCapacity(5)
            .fieldMonsterCapacity(5)
            .deckCards(Arrays.asList(new MonsterCard("Random", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING)))
            .build();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        player = Player.createFromConfiguration(playerConfiguration, "Test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorNegativeFusionCardIndex() {
        new FuseMonsterAction(-1, 0, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorNegativeBaseMonsterCardIndex() {
        new FuseMonsterAction(0, -1, 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorNegativeFuserMonsterCardIndex() {
        new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, -1);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructorEqualBaseMonsterCardIndexAndFuserMonsterCardIndex() {
        new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowed() {
        Hand hand = player.getHand();
        Field field = player.getField();
        hand.add(new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK));
        field.setMonster(0, new MonsterCard("Base Monster", 10, 50, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        field.setMonster(1, new MonsterCard("Fuser Monster", 40, 50, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        assertTrue(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPerformAction() {
        Hand hand = player.getHand();
        Field field = player.getField();
        Graveyard graveyard = player.getGraveyard();
        FusionCard fusionCard = new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK);
        MonsterCard baseMonster = new MonsterCard("Base Monster", 10, 50, MonsterModus.HEALING);
        MonsterCard fuserMonster = new MonsterCard("Fuser Monster", 40, 50, MonsterModus.HEALING);
        hand.add(fusionCard);
        field.setMonster(0, baseMonster);
        field.setMonster(1, fuserMonster);
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);

        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
        assertFalse(hand.contains(fusionCard));
        assertFalse(field.hasMonster(1));
        assertTrue(field.hasMonster(0));
        assertNotSame(baseMonster, field.getMonster(0));
        assertNotSame(fuserMonster, field.getMonster(0));

        assertTrue(graveyard.contains(fusionCard));
        assertTrue(graveyard.contains(baseMonster));
        assertTrue(graveyard.contains(fuserMonster));
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testIsActionAllowedNullPlayer() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testPerformActionNullPlayer() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedFusionCardIndexOverHandCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(5, 0, 1);
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionFusionCardIndexOverHandCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(5, 0, 1);
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedBaseMonsterCardIndexOverFieldMonsterCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 5, 1);
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionBaseMonsterCardIndexOverFieldMonsterCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 5, 1);
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedBaseFuserCardIndexOverFieldMonsterCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 5);
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionBaseFuserCardIndexOverFieldMonsterCapacity() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 5);
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedNonFusionCardInHand() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new MonsterCard("Random", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionNonFusionCardInHand() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new MonsterCard("Random", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedBaseMonsterCardNotOnField() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK));
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionBaseMonsterCardNotOnField() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK));
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsActionAllowedFuserMonsterCardNotOnField() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK));
        player.getField().setMonster(0, new MonsterCard("Base Monster", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        assertFalse(fuseMonsterAction.isActionAllowed(player));
    }

    @Test(expected = PlayerActionNotAllowedException.class)
    public void testPerformActionFuserMonsterCardNotOnField() {
        FuseMonsterAction fuseMonsterAction = new FuseMonsterAction(0, 0, 1);
        player.getHand().add(new FusionCard("Fusion Card", 50, FusionStat.ATTACK));
        player.getField().setMonster(0, new MonsterCard("Base Monster", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING));
        fuseMonsterAction.performAction(player);
    }
}
```

The specific question is about the `testIsActionAllowedNonFusionCardInHand` for example, should I there enforce all other conditions which could make a test fail? In this case it would be setting the other monsters on the field, as that might cause the test to fail.

Few extra notes:

- I prefer to explicitely list all interfaces a class implements, especially when using abstract superclasses.
- `static { assertTrue(true); }` is needed to stop Netbeans from complaining that it wants to remove the static import if I didn't use an assert yet...

If you would like to take a look at the other classes, then feel free to take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/skiwi2/TCG).

Comment: Did you really test that Exception gets correctly implemented? Talk about paranoid...

Answer (score 3):

I just want to make a few minor remarks, IMO these are more "preference" than "convention", so take 'em with a grain of salt

#### Test "sectioning"

> ```
> @Test
> public void testPerformAction() {
>     PlayerAction playerAction = new AbstractPlayerActionImpl();
>     Player player = new Player("Test", 100, new TurnActionImpl(), new Hand(5), new Field(5), new Deck(Arrays.asList(new MonsterCard("Test", 5, 5, MonsterModus.HEALING))), new Graveyard());
>     playerAction.performAction(player);
>     assertEquals(1, counter.get());
> }
> ```

taking this here as example:
I personally prefer really placing an empty line between the test sections: `given, when, then`. reformatting the example would look like that:

```
@Test
public void testPerformAction() {
    PlayerAction playerAction = new AbstractPlayerAction();
    Player player = new Player(/* [...] */);

    playerAction.performAction(player);

    assertEquals(1, counter.get());
}
```

#### Positive or Zero and similar:

> ```
> Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(baseMonsterCardIndex, "baseMonsterCardIndex");
> Arguments.requirePositiveOrZero(fuserMonsterCardIndex, "fuserMonsterCardIndex");
> ```

let's make a definitely non-working example...

```
new FuseMonsterAction(1000, 1001, 1002);
```

Well that went somewhat wrong :(

> ```
> Objects.requireNonNull(player, "player");
> Hand hand = Player.getHand(); //NPE inbound!
> ```

this one looks extremely NullPointerException prone to me. IMO you trust the Player Object too much that it will not have a null hand.